# Access PropertyGroup outside Target

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, target

## Problem

I defined 4 custom `Property` at a top level `PropertyGroup`:

- `AndroidResourcesFolder`
- `NugetFolder`
- `BrandingFiles` (uses `NugetFolder`)
- `AssemblyFile` (uses `BrandingFiles`)

... and I want to access `AndroidResourcesFolder` from a `Target`.

When accesing `AssemblyFile` from a `UsingTask`, the `Property` is properly *resolved*, but when I access `AndroidResourcesFolder` from a `Target`, Visual Studio reports that the `Property` has no value:

> error MSB4044: The "Mobile.Branding.Build.Task.CleanResources" task was not given a value for the required parameter "AndroidResourcesFolder".

## Code

This is my `.targets` file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <AndroidResourcesFolder>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Resources\</AndroidResourcesFolder>
    <NugetFolder>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\</NugetFolder>
    <BrandingFiles>$(NugetFolder)MonoAndroid81\</BrandingFiles>
    <AssemblyFile>$(BrandingFiles)\Amaris.Mobile.Branding.Build.dll</AssemblyFile>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <UsingTask
      TaskName="Mobile.Branding.Build.Task.CleanResources" AssemblyFile="$(AssemblyFile)" />
  <UsingTask
      TaskName="Mobile.Branding.Build.Task.ReadConfig" AssemblyFile="$(AssemblyFile)" />


  <Target Name="ReadConfig" >

    <PropertyGroup>
      <ConfigFile>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\branding.xml</ConfigFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Mobile.Branding.Build.Task.ReadConfig 
      ConfigFile="$(ConfigFile)" />

  </Target>

  <Target Name="BeforeClean" DependsOnTargets="ReadConfig" >

      <Mobile.Branding.Build.Task.CleanResources 
        AndroidResourcesFolder="$(AndroidResourcesFolder)" />

  </Target>

</Project>
```

## Question

Why were only 3 `Property` *resolved* and the rest (`AndroidResourcesFolder`) left out ?

Thanks!